# mysql select unique row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, duplicate-data

I have the following table - `mytable`:

```
----id----|----user_id----|----value-----|
----1-------------1------------- 9
----2-------------1------------- 8
----3-------------2 -------------11
----4-------------2-------------12
----5-------------3-------------11
----6-------------4-------------8
----7-------------1-------------3
```

I want to `SELECT * FROM mytable...` where value has a single record like this:

```
----id----|----user_id----|----value-----
----1-------------1-------------9
----4-------------2-------------12
----7-------------1-------------3
```

Note that value 8 and value 11 have duplicates and I removed all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
GROUP BY `value`
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
GROUP BY `value`
HAVING count(*) < 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a left join:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.user_id, T1.value
FROM yourtable T1
LEFT JOIN yourtable T2
ON T1.value = T2.value
AND T1.id <> T2.id
WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Column names are ambiguos: use `SELECT T1.id, T1.user_id,T1.value` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work fine for the question asked above..

SELECT T1.* 
FROM MYTABLE T1,
( 
 SELECT VALUE
 FROM MYTABLE
 GROUP BY VALUE
 HAVING COUNT(*)=1
) T2
WHERE T1.VALUE = T2.VALUE;

Regards,
Venk

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where 1 = (select count(t2.id)
                    from table1 t2
                    where t1.value = t2.value 
                    )
```

Hope it works.

PS: id has to be the unique key.